# Correct circuit design to light an LED

Tags: transistors, mosfet

I'm wondering if anyone sees an issue with this circuit. Basically using a button to control the Output Enable (OE) signal to a 74HC245 running at 3.3V.  When the button is not pressed, the OE is not asserted, is HIGH, and LED is on. When button is pushed OE goes low and LED goes off. Ignore button bounce issues, the button is just to demonstrate the basic logic of the circuit. My MOSFET would either be a 2N7000 or a BS170.

[image]

I believed I've reversed ground and power per the comment.  See image below.
[image]

Comment: Any reason for not using standard low side drive with an N-channel instead?

Comment: For a number of leds, you could use a 74hc245 or similar buffer. Pay attention to the maximum load current, but with modern leds, you probably only need a couple of mA per led.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Your fixed circuit will work perfectly. The only thing is 100 ohms will make LED current quite high, you may not want to burn up the LED or be so bright - depends on your LED though. The LEDs I use are too bright for general indicators with much smaller current. If your LEDs really need that much current, buy better LEDs.

WAS:

Yes, that's no way to use an N-type FET for high-side switching.

The internal diode will always pass 3.3V from pin 1 to 3, so LED will always be on.

The push button and pull-up resistor will however control the OE input by either being 0V or 3.3V, as no current will flow to FET gate.

Comment: "100 ohms will make LED current quite high" - Don't think so.  Standard red and green jelly bean LEDs have a Vf of around 1.8 V to 2.1 V.  That works out to a current range of 12 mA to 15 mA, for a part rated for a nominal current of 20 mA.

Comment: @AnalogKid The LEDs may be rated at 20mA, but modern LEDs don't need more than a few mA to be extremely bright signal indicators. You really do not want or need to use them at 20mA.

Comment: My point was that at 12 to 15 mA, nothing is going to "burn up."  If your LEDs are burning up on 12 mA, then I agree - buy better LEDs.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses.  I'll double check that resistor value with the led datasheet.

Answer (score 0):

In the schematic you posted, Q1 is semi-backwards.  Connect the source to GND, reverse the LED, and connect the LED anode to the 3.3 V source.  Now the transistor will act as a saturated switch for maximum LED brightness.

When the button is pressed, the Q1 drain will be pulled high by the LED leakage current.  This is not a reliable way to drive a logic input.  Connect a 10K resistor from the Q1 drain to the 3.3 V source, in parallwl with the LED and its resistor, to assure a firm logic high when the button is pressed.

When the button is released, the Q1 drain will be low.

Comment: Does this look better @AnalogKid